# Theme customizer hiding sections

Tags: themes, theme-customizer

I have customizer sections and fields setup which work fine if I don't include `wp_footer()` in my theme. Can someone shed some light on what's forcing the section and hides to be set to `hidden` the customizer section? I have included a GIF of the sections hiding below.

[image]

(the page takes a few seconds to load and then once the page is loaded, the sections hide)

As I said, if I remove `wp_footer()` from my theme, they work fine. The data is being saved and loaded up in the template and all the fields appear on every page as part of the theme's global sidebar and footer.

Comment: might be scripts are conflicting, as wp_footer() loads all scripts you can inspect the hidden section and check are the html elements appearing or it is totally blank.

Comment: You really must include `wp_footer()` in your theme if you are to expect the customizer preview to work as expected. For more see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37981

Comment: @WestonRuter yeah fully aware. Was trying to find out what the issue was so `wp_footer()` could stay in my theme and the customizer sections stop being hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'customizer_widgets_section_args', function ( $args ) {
  $args['active_callback'] = '__return_true';
  return $args;
} );
```

Adding this to my `functions.php` file ensured that the settings stayed visible no matter what page was visible.